# PHP regex lookahead not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a version number like `2.3.3 Release fhf47fh` and stripping out the periods to get a desired result of `233`

Using the pattern `/\d+(?=\.)\d+(?=\.)\d+/` with `preg_match`

The lookahead for the period does not seem to work as expected.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to compare the version, you can strip on the space and then use [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php).

If you just want the numeric representation, use a regex to simply use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) all non digits in the original version string.

```
$version = '2.3.3 Release';
echo preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $version);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to compare versions, simply trying to get a given version from a string

Comment: You could always substring the first space then use `preg_replace()`. But that's fair. I see you provided your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for all my test cases.

`preg_replace('/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).*$/', '$1$2$3', $version);`

Comment: Can you update the question with some of the test cases (if you're still looking for an answer, that is).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
$pattern = '~\d+(?:\.*\d*)*~';
```

For the string you've provided in the question:

```
if (preg_match('~\d+(?:\.*\d*)*~', $version, $matches))
    echo $matches[0]; // => 2.3.3
```

[**Regex101 demo.**](http://regex101.com/r/wM5nT4)